# How to run HP Fortify Scans over Django Application

Tags: django, fortify

When I run Fortify's SCA over a Django Application errors are returned due to improper syntax of some html template files.  This is because the Django framework will dynamically evaluate variables defined in the html.  Are there any fortify plugins that can be added so it can properly interpret a Django Application?